# How do you implement two T flip-flops in Verilog with the input and output equations?

Tags: verilog, flipflop, system-verilog

I have written this example to try to answer the question. There is one input, x, the clock, and three outputs. The clock pulses on and off, and x becomes 1 at random times for the positive edge of the clock.

The output should move the input of x from z1 to z3 with every clock pulse. For example, when x is equal to 1, three clock pulses in a row, the output should be 111. Similarly, if x is 1, 0, then 0, the outputs of z1, z2, and z3 should be 0, 0, and 1 respectively.

z1 works in my simulation. However, z2 and z3 remain constant at zero. It appears that the T flip-flop module does not change the value of q. However, I have simulated the flip-flop module by itself with no issue.

When I run the top level module, I get a warning message that t1, t0, q1, and q0 remain constant at zero. However, from the equations, t0 should become one the moment x becomes one, because of "t0 = ~q0&x + ..."

I have tried many variations of this code; putting the `always` function in and around different sections of code, initiating and not initiating values for the t's and q's, defining the t's and q's as wires and or regs. I have also tried blocking and nonblocking variations on the equations, when inside `always` blocks.

```
module TwoFFwithEquations(
    input x, 
     input clk,
    
     output reg z1, 
     output reg z2, 
     output reg z3 
     
     );
     
     reg t1, t0;
     wire q1, q0;
     
        initial begin
            t1 = 0;
            t0 = 0;
        end
     
        TFF tff1(t1, clk, q1);
        TFF tff0(t0, clk, q0);

        always@(posedge clk) begin   

             t1 = q1&~q0 + ~q1&q0;
             t0 = ~q0&x + q0&~x;    
            
             z1 = x; 
             z2 = q0; 
             z3 = q1; 
        end
endmodule
```

```
module TFF(
    input T,
     input clk,
     
     output reg Q
     );
     
     initial begin
        Q = 0;
     end
     
     always@(posedge clk) begin
        case(T)
            1'b0: Q<=Q;
            1'b1: Q<=~Q;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is operator precedence.  There are 3 types of operators in the expression:

```
~q0&x + q0&~x
```

1. Unary `~` has the highest precedence
2. Binary `+` has the next highest
3. Binary `&` is the lowest of the 3 operators.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.3.2 *Operator precedence*.  That means that Verilog evaluates the expression as:

```
(~ q0) & (x + q0) & (~ x)
```

You should use parentheses to have it evaluate the way that you want:

```
         t0 <= (~q0 & x) + (q0 & ~x);
```

When I make that change and a similar change for the `t1` assignment, I see `z2` and `z3` go to 1.

---

Although it did not make a difference in your simlation, for sequential logic, you should use nonblocking assignments:

```
    always @(posedge clk) begin
         t1 <= (q1&~q0) + (~q1&q0);
         t0 <= (~q0&x) + (q0&~x);
         z1 <= x;
         z2 <= q0;
         z3 <= q1;
    end
```

Comment: In general, when using _any_ programming language, you should use parentheses rather than using the built-in operator precedence. Operator precedence provides an endless source of programming errors. If it were up to me, programming languages would report an _error_ if an expression was encountered that would be ambiguous except for the rules of operator precedence. An expression which _might_ be ambiguous to a human, should be treated as if it really _is_ ambiguous, rather than being given a default interpretation.